# is there a rule of thumb to know if i'm modifying a value or a referenced value?

Tags: python, scipy, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following :

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np

pts = np.random.rand(30, 2)
hull = ConvexHull(pts)
foo = hull.points
foo[0] = 4
print(pts[0]) # -> [4. 4.]
bar = foo[0]
bar[0] = 8    
print(pts[0]) # -> [8. 4.]
```

How am i supposed to know that modifying *hull.points* (or foo, a reference to hull.points) is modifying *pts* ?

The documentation only say :

```
points: ndarray of double, shape (npoints, ndim)
        Coordinates of input points.
```

The inspector in pycharm also tell me that both foo and hull.points are a ndarray and nothing in the code, documentation, inspector tell me that my variables are, in fact, pointers referencing the same  value (yes, i come from C, sorry)

It can go wrong horribly quickly because if i directly modify a single element of "pts" (the 2D array holding all the values referenced by my other variable/pointers) it modify all my variables too and my convex hull "bar" isn't convex anymore :

```
...
pts[0] = 16
print(bar) # -> [16. 16.]
```

**unless** i call again

```
pts = np.random.rand(30, 2)
print(bar) # -> [16. 16.]
print(pts[0]) # -> [some random value]
```

pts apparently became a whole different object in a new memory location so, in this specific case, bar is not a reference to pts anymore.

And it can go on forever : if i now modify foo = hull.points then bar isn't a reference to foo anymore (well... it's a reference to the "old foo" which is not accessible anymore)

**My use case** : with all the arguments passing and return values of differents method : I'm loosing track of all my reference and values. I end up unknowingly returning a list of value despite the fact that i modified (also unknowingly) a reference (and therefore the original ndarray) and i don't even know anymore if my returned value is a reference or a standalone object that can be safely modified without messing up everything else.

full simplified use case :

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np

pts = np.random.rand(30, 2)
hull = ConvexHull(pts)
foo = hull.points
foo[0] = 4
print(pts[0]) # -> [4. 4.]
bar = foo[0]
bar[0] = 8    
print(pts[0]) # -> [8. 4.]

qux = bar[0]  # WOOPS /!\ qux isn't a reference to an ndarray element, it's just a "float" value
bar[0] = 16   # BUT  this is a reference so i end up modifying pts BUT not qux /!\

print(pts[0], foo[0], bar, qux) # -> [16.  4.] [16.  4.] [16.  4.] 8.0 

qux = bar      # /!\ qux is now again a reference to pts
qux[0] = 128
print(pts[0], foo[0], bar, qux) # -> [128.   4.] [128.   4.] [128.   4.] [128.   4.]

qux = foo[0]   # remember that qux = bar[0] didn't create a reference ?
qux[0] = 256   # but in this case, it is ! bar[0] is just a single float value while foo[0] is a reference to a ndarray
print(pts[0], foo[0], bar, qux) # -> [256.   4.] [256.   4.] [256.   4.] [256.   4.]
```

And since this is so much "fun". Now that i have qux and bar referencing foo[0], what happens to qux and bar if i say foo = None ? Nothing... qux an bar are still referencing pts[0] even if i never explicitly said so ... i'm so lost.

I'm also wondering if i'm not in a special case because it's numpy/scipy/ndarray. i never struggled like this before. (i got lucky ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python variables are always references. But the nature of stored value type defines it's behaviour. Variables can be *mutable* or *immutable*. Mutables are: int, float, str, tuple, etc. Immutables are most collections: dict, list, set, etc.

Consider this example:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
my_list = [a, b, c]
new_list = my_list

new_list[0] = 0

>>> print(a, b, c)
... 1 2 3

>>> print(my_list)
... [0, 2, 3]

>>> print(new_list)
... [0, 2, 3]
```

What happens here: you do change 0th element of my_list. But since it is `int` and is immutable, that 0th element will be assigned new value and will so a new reference. Yet `a` will be still pointing to the same value as before.

This is basically the idea of immutable objects: changing it creates a new object in memory and updates pointer to point to this new object. So when you do `a += 1` you in fact create a new `int` object and set `a` to point to that new object.

But `my_list` is a `list` and is mutable. So changing it will not change the reference. This way when you do `new_list = my_list` you create variable `new_list` that references the same object as `my_list`. So changing one will change another.

---

Variable never holds a value itself, it's always a reference. But changing variable doesn't mean changing referenced object. For immutable object changing value is changing reference, for mutable objects changing value is changing it's content. But there is never a mutable object that isn't a collection of some sort. So when you change a mutable item of a list, list stays the same, but reference for that item is changed to a *new* reference. So that contents of a list are changing, but the actual list object stays the same.

Basically any data structure in python can be drilled down to immutables. Is it a list of int's? Well, there are your immutables. Is it a list of a list of int's? One level deeper there are still immutables. Is it a class instance? I bet it has fields, and fields are no different than any other data structure. You get the point.

Here is another example:

```
a, b = 1, 2
my_list = [a, b]

>>> print(id(a), id(b))
... 4325931056 4325931088

>>> print(id(my_list[0]), id(my_list[1]))
... 4325931056 4325931088

>>> my_list[0] += 10
>>> print(id(a), id(b))
... 4325931056 4325931088  # a still has the same reference

>>> print(id(my_list[0]), id(my_list[1]))
... 4325931376 4325931088  # my_list[0] now has a new reference 

>>> b += 10
>>> print(id(b))
... 4325931408  # b now has a new reference

>>> print(id(my_list[1]))
... 4325931088  # my_list[1] reference is still the same
```

Comment: are you saying that it's always a reference except when it's immutable then it's a value ? i almost get it ... my_list doesn't reference a,b,c otherwise there would be a way to modify one by modifying the other (i tried). UNLESS the modification create a new object even if said object is mutable, eg following your example : my_list  = [c,b,a] then the reference new_list -> my_list is lost. (new_list still contain [0,2,3])

Comment: Thank you, i think i get it. i'll check again tomorrow and try some stuff. i find it surprisingly difficult to understand for a beginner-friendly language. And it's not even some weird edge-case, it's a fundamental basis of the language.

Comment: Just search some docs and articles. It's not that complicated and only becomes noticeable in rare cases.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer describes the basic Python context - everything is an object, variables are references to objects, and some objects are immutable, while others mutable.

I'll elaborate on your example, since `numpy` adds some nuances.

Make an array and assign it to variable `pts`:

```
In [71]: pts = np.random.rand(30,2)
In [72]: id(pts)
Out[72]: 139777500963904
```

`ConvexHull` is a `scipy` import.  Without looking at its docs or code, I deduce that it is a class definition:

```
#hull = ConvexHull(pts)
#foo = hull.points
```

`hull` is probably a `ConvexHull` instance, and at some point in the initialization there's a:

```
self.points = pts
```

In other words the input argument gets assigned (by reference) to the `points` attribute.  As per standard python practice that's just a reference assignment, without any copying.

So effectively you are doing:

```
In [73]: foo = pts
In [74]: id(foo)
Out[74]: 139777500963904             # same array object created by the rand call
```

`pts[0]` is an indexing that returns a `view` of the array.  Since `pts` is 2d, it could also be written as `pts[0,:]`.

```
In [75]: pts[0]
Out[75]: array([0.79172504, 0.52889492])
In [76]: foo[0]
Out[76]: array([0.79172504, 0.52889492])    # same values
```

A list contains references, so indexing returns one of those objects.  Indexing of arrays is more complicated.  Unless it's `object` dtype, indexing returns a new array, which may reference the original array's values, or may be a copy.

Since `foo` is the same array as `pts`, this modification of `foo` is also seen when we look at `pts`:

```
In [77]: foo[0] = 4
In [78]: foo[0]
Out[78]: array([4., 4.])
In [79]: pts[0]
Out[79]: array([4., 4.])
```

We can assign that `view` of `foo/pts` to variable.  Again, that's just a variable assignment, no new copy.

```
In [80]: bar = foo[0]
In [81]: bar
Out[81]: array([4., 4.])
```

Sometimes the `__array_interface__` is a handy way of checking whether something is a `view` or `copy`:

```
In [82]: pts.__array_interface__
Out[82]: 
{'data': (43476672, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (30, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [83]: bar.__array_interface__
Out[83]: 
{'data': (43476672, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (2,),
 'version': 3}
```

Interpreting this can be tricky, but here the `data` line has the same number.  As a crude 'c' parallel, that number is a pointer to the databuffer used by the array.  Here `bar` and `pts` use the same databuffer, but `bar` can only look at 2 elements of that (16 bytes), not all.

```
In [84]: bar.shape
Out[84]: (2,)
```

Changing an element of `bar` changes the corresponding element of the `foo/pts` array.

```
In [85]: bar[0] = 0
In [86]: bar
Out[86]: array([0., 4.])
In [87]: foo[0]
Out[87]: array([0., 4.])
```

In answer to your initial question, assume when mutating array (and list) elements, that you could be change values of the array it was derived from.  Simple variable assignment does not produce copies (that applies to variables passed into/out of functions). `numpy` uses `view` where possible to avoid unnecessary copies, but for some indexing operations a copy is inevitable.